What are the command line parameters that I can pass to the PostGIS installer?
I want to silently install PostGIS on a Windows machine with PostgreSQL using Ansible.
To do so, I need to be able to run the PostGIS installer on the commandline, with the required options as arguments to the installer.
I found the separate installers (in contrast to using the stackbuilder), but I don't know how/which options I can specify on the commandline. It's a Nullsoft installer, which only seems to have a handful of options. The GUI PostGIS installer shows more though, so how can I set those options as well?

A comment on the downvote would be helpful to understand how I can improve this (and future) questions.
